# Javascript troubles with IE 9

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

In C#, Asp.net, I'm creating Javascript code through my code-behind :

```
var silverlightControl = null;
function PluginLoaded(sender, args) 
{
  silverlightControl = sender.getHost();
  silverlightControl.Content.SilverlightScriptableObject.PerformRfidRead(); //**1**  
} 

function CallSilverlight() 
{
  silverlightControl.Content.SilverlightScriptableObject.PerformRfidRead(); //**2**  
}

var tid = setInterval(RefreshTimer, 2000);
function RefreshTimer()
{
  CallSilverlight();
}
```

It works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome but cannot seems to work on IE 9 ! The PluginLoaded Method is always called properly. But it seems that my "silverlightControl" var lose its value between methods calls...

When calling my Method "PerformRfidRead()" directly after sender.getHost() (cf. **1**), everything is normal. When letting the timer do the call every 2 seconds (cf. **2**), it seems my var is empty and I receive the following error message :

**Content » : null object or undefined**

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not an answer, but consider putting your Javascript code in an external `js` file and using [RegisterClientScriptInclude()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2552td66.aspx) to reference it from your page. That would improve your code's readability and maintainability. Editing your question in the same way would also be welcome, all these calls to `ScriptBuilder.Append()` are making me dizzy.

Comment: Hey, there you go, should be more readable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally put my finger on this problem :

Firefox, Chrome and IE9 have different behavior regarding timers !

My RefreshTimer method was called too early and the PluginLoaded method couldn't be called soon enough to initialize the silverlightControl object !

Therefore, I corrected by doing this :

```
function CallSilverlight() 
{
  if(silverlightControl != null)
  {
    silverlightControl.Content.SilverlightScriptableObject.PerformRfidRead(); //**2**  
  }
}
```

Hope this can help someone...